# can you help when to use field and when to use parameter and variable in jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using ireport 5.6.0 and i want to generate a report which contains a single data like "name of employee" and also tabular data like employee dependent's name list details. please help me what i have to use and in which way i have to pass data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use textfield for the "name".
and use table for tabular data related to employee dependents.

for that you need to pass a Map parameter as-
name , and list of dependents.
then u can set datasource for table.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i have a doubt about this after adding textfield name  i have to add it as a parameter or field?

Comment: and kindly tell me the exact datasource class to configure the tabular value

Comment: read this : https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-jasperreports-server-your-database